# Accessing a file with an external program immediately after closing stream. (C++)

Tags: c++, windows, filesystems, javac

So I am having a weird issue where I am trying to write a file and then run an external program (in this case, the java compiler) on it in rapid succession. There seems to be a lag time between when I close the ofstream and when the external program is able to see the file in the filesystem. If I run the program immediately after closing the file, it spits out an error claiming it cannot find the file I just wrote. However if I use std::filesystem::exists() then it seems to think it does exist.

I first thought to just busy-loop it with some sleeps, however since std::filesystem::exists() is reporting that the file is in-fact there, I seem to have no way of checking if the external program will be able to read it before executing it. So I have no idea how long to busy loop for if I went that route, and I'd rather not have 5-10 second delays if possible.

My gut feeling says that this is platform dependent, since I am dealing with the response time of the filesystem, but I have also run into similar issues to this previously in this project where I will attempt to delete a file very soon after writing it and then getting errors saying "this file is being used by another program etc...". And yes, I am closing all of my ofstreams before trying this.

I also know that it is timing dependent, since if I breakpoint the program right before the call to the Java compiler and then wait like 10 seconds before resuming, everything works as expected, however unreliably. I am on Windows, using C++2a. I would prefer a cross-platform solution (if this is even a problem on Linux), however I am willing to implement it separately for Windows and Linux if absolutely need be. I am pretty lost as to where to proceed debugging...

#### Code

```
//Create Source File
//Ex... %Temp%/4j783jy7f3jy879/source.java
auto sourceFileName = temp / "source.java"; 
std::ofstream sourceFile(sourceFileName);
sourceFile << source;
sourceFile.close();

//Compile File
//This is not throwing, so this thinks its there...
if (!std::filesystem::exists(sourceFileName)) throw "I can't see the file"; 

//If I smack a breakpoint here and go to the temp folder, source.java definitley exist
//If I then wait like 5-10 seconds before resuming it works sometimes......

// Essentially runs "javac.exe source.java"
// Will probably fail due to not finding the file
secsystem(javacLoc, { sourceFileName.string() });
```

#### Error

```
E:/3rd_party/lib/jdk-14.0.1/bin/javac.exe C:\Users\Mike\AppData\Local\Temp\3BHJLOQRWX\source.java
error: file not found: C:\Users\Mike\AppData\Local\Temp\3BHJLOQRWX\source.java
Usage: javac <options> <source files>
use --help for a list of possible options
```

#### Source

If it is applicable here is the source this snippit is from: [JavaBlock.cpp](https://github.com/Mike111177/EngFlow/blob/ecbc76c6f8a70f1940aa20bc929faf7eb4964d7b/src/Flow/blocks/codeblocks/JavaBlock.cpp#L29)

Also, I get the feeling some will ask, here is the source of secsystem(): [SecureSystem.cpp](https://github.com/Mike111177/EngFlow/blob/ecbc76c6f8a70f1940aa20bc929faf7eb4964d7b/src/Util/SecureSystem.cpp)

Comment: The file exists, but it seems that something is temporarily masking it. I would try disabling every anti-malware tool on the system.

Comment: No anti-malware is running on this computer, however even if there was, I need this to work on computers that happen to have anti malware installed lol.

Comment: What you're describing is not normal behavior in Windows. When a file is created, it immediately exists, and if it's opened with data access, typically the open shares read/execute and write/append access, which means it can be opened again with any access except for delete/rename access. When I see weird filesystem behavior, my brain jumps to anti-malware programs that insert filter drivers in the storage device stack. Filter drivers can change just about all filesystem semantics for what can be done when and where, results and side effects, and what's visible to whom. All bets are off.

Comment: Ok, in that case, since I am not running any anti-virus/anti-malware, is there a way I can probe the system to see if I am about to bump into this error, so at least in a worst case scenario I can busy loop until it works?

Comment: Since this strangeness doesn't appear to affect the current process that creates the file, try spawning a child process that waits for the file to exist, and wait for the child to exit with a reasonable timeout (i.e. `CreateProcessW` and `WaitForSingleObject`, and on timeout `TerminateProcess`). The child can use the same executable with a particular command-line argument such as `--waitforfile <"path\to\file">`.